# Wpf Application Update threw Hockey.SDK

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-installer, hockeyapp

After integrating my application with HockeySDK.

I wanted to test out the AsyncUpdate functionality, but getting the following error:

[image: Msi Installation Error]

After enabling msi logs via registry. I also get the following:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 2/23/2018  7:21:23  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (40:C8) [07:21:23:897]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (40:C8) [07:21:23:897]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (40:D8) [07:21:23:906]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (40:D8) [07:21:23:906]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 2
MSI (c) (40:D8) [07:21:23:906]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\pljanot\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp65C9.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (40:D8) [07:21:23:906]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Users\pljanot\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp65C9.msi 3: -2147286960 
MSI (c) (40:D8) [07:21:23:908]: MainEngineThread is returning 1620
=== Verbose logging stopped: 2/23/2018  7:21:23 ===
```

My code to perform update is based on Hockey integration guideline.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string _hockeyAppId = "id_here";
        HockeyClient.Current.Configure(_hockeyAppId);

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var bootstrapper = new WpfBootstraper();
        bootstrapper.Run();

        await HockeyClient.Current.SendCrashesAsync();

        await HockeyClient.Current.CheckForUpdatesAsync(true, () =>
        {
            if (Application.Current.MainWindow != null) { Application.Current.MainWindow.Close(); }
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be because you are updating to the same version already installed or because you hit the install button twice. I've had a lot of trouble with HockeyApp in testing. It doesn't seem very viable for ordinary users.

Comment: Well If the version was not correct the update won't be triggered. I tried even with demo application and adding the hockey update failed with the same error. I even ask on Hockey github but they state that their have nothing to do with api. Probably I missing something. Did it work for your wpf application ?

Comment: I mean it has issues if your app version is different than the version you said it was from management.
I don't believe HockeyApp should be used (just in my testing, it was way too flaky with sometimes not working and sometimes having to redownload). I recommend trying [Omaha](https://github.com/google/omaha/) or [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows)

Comment: So true thank you for recommendation.